# Javascript Bizarre Output

Tags: javascript, console.log

Why does this give the output as;

finance

the code is attached

```js
console.log(("f"+"i"+ +"a"+"c"+"e").toLowerCase())
```

Comment: Because you have an invalid cast operation there at `+ "a"`, and returns `NaN`.
Therefore it gives you the output `"fi" + NaN + "ce"`.

Answer (score 7):

`+"a"` attempts to cast "a" as a number, but it's not a number, so that results in [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) (not a number). So then you have this:

```js
"f" + "i" + NaN + "c" + "e"
```

At this point, adding left to right is string concatenation. `NaN` gets coerced to the string `"NaN"`. Your final string is this:

```js
"fiNaNce".toLowerCase()
// "finance"
```